# Apache-FOP line break

Tags: xslt, apache-fop

XML to PDF conversion using Apache FOP, how to insert line break between lines.

am trying all the possibilities with the below code.

```
<fo:block>
    Line 1 &#xA;   /// Not Working
    Line 2 &#xA;   /// Not Working
    Line 3 <br />  /// Not working
</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want insert line break inside `<fo:block/>`. inserting `<fo:block/>` instead of `&#x0A;` will also work like `<br/>` in HTML.

```
<fo:block>
    Line 1 <fo:block/>
    Line 2 <fo:block/>
    Line 3 <fo:block/>
</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer for line break,

```
<fo:block>Line 1</fo:block>
<fo:block>Line 2</fo:block>
<fo:block>Line 3</fo:block>
```